# Excel 2013/2016 not updating values while workbook is minimized

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following setup:

1. 1 Workbook named `Workbook1` with the value `123` in A1
2. 1 Workbook named `Workbook2` with value `=[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1` in A1

Now, when I go and change the value of `Workbook1` to something else the value gets updated as expected in `Workbook2`.

But sadly, when I minimize `Workbook2` and than change the value in `Workbook1` and than restore `Workbook2` to verify if the value has been updated it still shows the old value.

Notice:

- after restoring the window even if I calculate (F9) or
  calculate the whole sheet (SHIFT + F9) the value doesn't update
- when I add a new Worksheet to `Workbook2` the value gets updated (was more a coincidence that I found that)

Is there a way to fix this?

**Update:**

As Máté Juhász already mentioned in the comments there are various ways to actually update the value.

I myself found that switching the View triggers the cell to update or simply chaning the Display ruler, Display gridlines, Display headers property they all triggered the cell to update its value.

I also had a look at:

```
MsgBox Application.Range("A1").Value
MsgBox Application.Range("A1").Text
```

Both, output the correct value while the old value is still visible.

So a thought came up that all those operations that trigger the cell have one thing in common the screen gets updated, so my current "solution" is the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)

Dim oldValue As Boolean
oldValue = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = Not oldValue
Application.ScreenUpdating = oldValue

End Sub
```

With the knowledge of the issue just being a not updating screen, I also tried to simply scroll my cell out of the visible range and scroll back - this also did update the cell's value.

Also, now it makes sense why F9 and SHIFT + F9 didn't trigger the cell to update, since the value is already correct, there just simply isn't a thing for the calculation to update - since it's already there, just not visible.

Comment: Is it 2013 or 2016? have you tried both versions? Maybe on different computers? Does it happen in all workbooks?

Comment: @MátéJuhász 2013 and 2016, yes tried both versions - also, tried on different computers - yes, it happens on all workbooks

Comment: I've tried and have the same issue, good spotting! It seems to be a bug. Actually you don't need to insert a new sheet, just changing to another sheet then back, or switching to print preview refreshes the value from the other workbook.

Comment: @MátéJuhász - thx for your comment, see my update

Comment: That sounds like a solution, please post it as an answer, instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If both files are in same folder, it gets immediately automatically updated across the files.

If both files are in different folders (in my case different disk partitions also), it doesn't get updated. To update, first save the file in which you have made the change. Then go to the other file, select the cell to Edit (pressing F2), press Enter without doing any change. It gets updated.

It may not be a bug, it may be related to "Updating external links" settings, there are so many settings of these that I could not figure out. Someone knowing about that might shed some light.